# SFTP client connects, but stops at OpenSSH version

Tags: openssl, ssh, sftp

I have a weird situation which I have been unable to determine the root cause for. I have a service I need to connect via SFTP to on the internet. When connecting via SFTP this is what I see when running it in debug mode:

```
[user1@localhost-live ~]$ sftp -oIdentityFile=~/.ssh/privatekey -oPort=4321 -vvv user1@1.2.3.4
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b FIPS  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 1.2.3.4 originally 1.2.3.4
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 1.2.3.4 is address
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 1.2.3.4 originally 1.2.3.4
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 1.2.3.4 [1.2.3.4] port 4321.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/privatekey type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/privatekey-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
```

As you can see the connection is established and my system provides the private key, but after the entry "Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9", the client and server just stop communicating. The server doesn't drop the connection, or continues. It's just stuck.

I thought the issue could be related to the version of OpenSSH and or OpenSSL. Neither one seems to be the case. I'm running on the client side OpenSSH 7.9p1 and OpenSSL 1.1.1b. The server on the other end is running with the following settings:

```
 # override default of no subsystems
 Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
 # sftp only on port 4321 (it's exposed to internet)
 Match LocalPort 4321
 ForceCommand internal-sftp
 X11Forwarding no
 AllowTCPForwarding no
 ChrootDirectory /mnt/efs/sftp/%u
```

And this is OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips running on Red Hat 7.4.

What is weird is that the client that I was using in the above instance is a Fedora 30 version and its pretty close to bleeding edge.

I run locally on my machine Manjaro Linux and when I try to connect to the same system, the result is different. The versions I'm running there are OpenSSH_8.0p1 and OpenSSL 1.1.1b. I'm able to connect without issue. Below is the output;

```
 [user1@user1-m380 ~]$ sftp -oIdentityFile=~/.ssh/privatekey -oPort=4321 -vvv user1@1.2.3.4
 OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
 debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user1/.ssh/config
 debug1: /home/user1/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 1.2.3.4 is address
 debug2: ssh_connect_direct
 debug1: Connecting to 1.2.3.4 [1.2.3.4] port 4321.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/privatekey type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/privatekey-cert type -1
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
 debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
 debug1: Authenticating to 1.2.3.4:4321 as 'user1'
 debug3: put_host_port: [1.2.3.4]:4321
 debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
 debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:1177
 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [1.2.3.4]:4321
 debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
 debug3: send packet: type 20
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug3: receive packet: type 20
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
 debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
 debug2: languages ctos: 
 debug2: languages stoc: 
 debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
 debug2: reserved 0 
 debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
 debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
 debug2: languages ctos: 
 debug2: languages stoc: 
 debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
 debug2: reserved 0 
 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug3: send packet: type 30
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 debug3: receive packet: type 31
 debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:IUUTqOtpUjNSRAOgze0OiVsUoLhm8sgvhTcOtNgFTfe
 debug3: put_host_port: [1.2.3.4]:4321
 debug3: put_host_port: [1.2.3.4]:4321
 debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
 debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:1177
 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [1.2.3.4]:4321
 debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
 debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:1177
 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [1.2.3.4]:4321
 debug1: Host '[1.2.3.4]:4321' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:1177
 debug3: send packet: type 21
 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
 debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug3: receive packet: type 21
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
 debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user1/.ssh/privatekey  explicit
 debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
 debug3: send packet: type 5
 debug3: receive packet: type 7
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
 debug3: receive packet: type 6
 debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug3: send packet: type 50
 debug3: receive packet: type 51
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
 debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
 debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
 debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
 debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/privatekey
 Enter passphrase for key '/home/user1/.ssh/privatekey': 
 debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:y1HxyI+tlh1DfEuWDjLHLOSUGXo44YzNnrBSrxFh7vG
 debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
 debug3: send packet: type 50
 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
 debug3: receive packet: type 52
 debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
 Authenticated to 1.2.3.4 ([1.2.3.4]:4321).
 debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
 debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
 debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
 debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
 debug2: channel 0: send open
 debug3: send packet: type 90
 debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
 debug3: send packet: type 80
 debug1: Entering interactive session.
 debug1: pledge: network
 debug3: receive packet: type 80
 debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
 debug3: receive packet: type 91
 debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
 debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
 debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20
 debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
 debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
 debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
 debug3: send packet: type 98
 debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
 debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
 debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
 debug3: receive packet: type 99
 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
 debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
 debug2: Remote version: 3
 debug2: Server supports extension "posix-rename@openssh.com" revision 1
 debug2: Server supports extension "statvfs@openssh.com" revision 2
 debug2: Server supports extension "fstatvfs@openssh.com" revision 2
 debug2: Server supports extension "hardlink@openssh.com" revision 1
 debug2: Server supports extension "fsync@openssh.com" revision 1
 Connected to user1@1.2.3.4.
 debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:16 I:1
 debug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> / size 0
 sftp>
```

Unlike the previous connection, we are able to obtain the version of OpenSSH that's running on the target system and we are off to the races.

From this information provided can anyone let me know what I may be doing wrong here? Am I missing the configuration piece on the client side that would not let me connect? Could the issue be on the target system?

Comment: This looks more about configuration than about security. Voting to migrate it to serverfault.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34472753/481815

Comment: Hi ThoriumBR, I'm fine with that. Thx.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Why serverfault and not superuser? From personal experience, SF dislikes anything that can be reproduced on a single machine.

Comment: this is probably a networking problem that does not reproduce on localhost

Comment: There might be a DPI firewall blocking the traffic once it sees an SSH dialog on an uncommon port. Just some quick guess though since nothing is known of your network and the connectivity between both hosts.

Comment: I wanted to add that in the end the issue was related to the port used for this process. We have PAN firewalls which expect traffic like SSH, or http/https to go through RFC standard ports. Any traffic the system sees as designated for a different port, but has the characteristics of traffic that is meant for SSH which should run on port 22, or http/https which has port 80/443 standardized, our firewalls stop the traffic. In the end the server we needed to connect to set SFTP traffic on port 22 so we could connect. Thanks for all the help.